# SQL Server - evaluate a function in a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a piece of dynamic SQL inside part of which retrieves a function dependent on other results from the query, but also uses these results to evaluate this function. I know eval() does not exist in SQL so what do I use?

A very simplified version

```
select reading, functiontype, @result = eval(f.functionformula)
from readingstables r
join functiontable f on (r.functiontype = f.functiontype)
```

So basically (note these are only example formulae) I want to use the functionformula which is related to a set of readings via the formulatype

if f.functiontype == 'A' then  f.functionformula = reading * reading
if f.functiontype == 'B' then  f.functionformula = reading * costant / anothervalue 
    //etc etc

The real version is a huge piece of dynamic SQL in a stored procedure that drives a cursor. I would prefer to do it in one query but suspect I might have to compromise and have a second dynamic query driven from the first.

Comment: Your best approach is probably what you mention . . . two dynamic queries.  The first looks up the correct function; the second uses it.  This gives you flexibility on function arguments, and even return types.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the [POWER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) function:

```
Case functionType
    When 'A' Then Power( reading, 2 )
    When 'B' Then Power( reading, 3 )
    ...
    End
```

You could even get super fancy like so:

```
Power( reading, Ascii( functionType ) - Ascii('A') + 2 )
```

---

**Edit**

Given your change to your OP, beyond dynamic SQL, there is no way to dynamically execute a function call. You could create a UDF which takes the function type parameter and executes the correct expression however the UDF itself would need to be a large Case expression.

```
Create Function FunctionTypeExpression( @FunctionType char(1) )
Returns float
As

Return Case @FunctionType
    When 'A' Then ..expression 1
    When 'B' Then ..expression 2
    ...
```

One note in this, you will need to make the return value of the function compatible with any possible return type from the expressions. Hopefully, they are all numeric. If they are not all numeric (or all text), then a more detailed explanation for why this is not the case would be needed.

Comment: As I said that is the simplified version of a function - the real versions have multiple parameters and are user maintained - hence database table

Comment: @EricHewett - This is one of the reasons it is helpful to have more details about what you are actually trying to accomplish. It would have been better not to include the formulas unless they are really are mostly powers of another value.

Comment: @EricHewett - Do the expressions include values from the rest of the query (i.e., other columns) or are they wholly contained expressions but simply different depending on function type? If wholly contained, then a single UDF will work, if not, you will have to dynamically assemble the call for the given expression based on the function type. Still, I'd be curious to know the nature of the problem that would require something like a expression engine.

Comment: there are a set of formulas held in one table and a set of constants which may or may not be used by the formula. A formula then relates by type to a set of readings.

Comment: try again - there are a set of formulas held in one table and a set of constants which may or may not be used by the formula. A formula then relates by type to a set of readings. The formulas and constants are user maintained and provide calibration of the readings. One formula tends to dominate but not exclusively - hence my problem (To explain further the original source code was created and lost before my time - I have had to reverse engineer it (from Delphi) and rewrite it as a stored procedure. )

Comment: @EricHewett - It sounds like a variant of a rules engine. What you need is an expression engine wherein you replace the variable portions of a mathematical expression with the values you want. Long ago, I did a project which had a similar requirement and I was forced to use a third party COM component to achieve that. Now, you might be able to find something in C# and create a CLR function to do it.

Comment: @EricHewett - Expanding on my previous response, it sounds like you need something like http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2007/05/05/calculator-net-calculator-that-evaluates-math-expressions.aspx which you drop into the CLR in SQL Server and pass it a formula.

Comment: thanks for that - I haven't tried that before - I coded a mod the stored proc for testing 2morro - I suspect your idea is more performant